# How not to distribute reads in pgpool

Tags: postgresql, replication, pgpool

I want to use pgpool to replicate one database to another.  I want to do my processing on my master database (reads/writes/inserts/deletes), replicate that database to another database as it is modified and have other reads be directed to the replicated database.

As I read the pgpool documentation it appears that reads will be distributed across all databases in the cluster. Is there a way to not do that and direct one class of reads to one database and another class of read/writes to the master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, pgpool is an all or nothing solution.  All you can control is the precentage of read queries going to each host, not what kinds of (read) queries.